# Synonymilatify [removing-whitespace] and [whitespace]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Proposing a synonym:

[removing-whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/removing-whitespace) (303 questions)

[whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whitespace) (2,426 questions).

The remove- tag has no subscribers and no wiki. The plain tag is more appropriate; it has a wiki, subscribers, and more widespread use on questions, including the subject of removal. A/B problems would benefit from not being pigeon-holed by pre-suggesting the solution through the tag.

---

As mentioned by Bryan P, there is also the language whitespace; some of the questions with the [whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whitespace) tag are related to the language. So, the proposed resolution is:

1) create the tag [whitespace-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whitespace-language) and re-tag from [whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whitespace) as appropriate

2) merge [removing-whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/removing-whitespace) with [whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whitespace)

Comment: are these tags even needed?

Comment: @DanielA.White, there is a programming language called [Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29), which the tag *would* be valid for. But since it's an esoteric language, I sincerely doubt there is even one question relating to the language.

Comment: @JamesWebster http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541599/bug-in-whitespace-code

Comment: ^ Now I'm trying to figure out why a moderator came back 2 years after that ridiculous and obviously troll question was deleted and **undeleted it**! It had the [tag:fun] tag on it, doesn't that make it obviously not genuine?

Comment: The css property whitespace usually deals with line breaks and collapsing whitespace, not removing whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like `whitespace (language)` for those few that relate to the language. And then merge `whitespace` and `removing-whitespace`